# How do I specify "TLSv1.2 protocol or later" for Apache httpd

Tags: apache, https

The extra/httpd-ssl.conf file shipped with Apache httpd 2.4.20 says

> By the end of 2016, only the TLSv1.2 protocol or later should remain
>   in use

But unlike with SSLCipherSuite, they do not give an example of how to do this.  I could do

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
```

but that would not appear to meet the "or later" part. Does

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1
```

cover it?  Are there others that should be disabled, too?

Comment: There is currently no TLS1.3 - it is still under development. It still needs to be finalized and then it must find it's way into your OpenSSL and Apache version...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLS 1.3 is not yet released, so, for now:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
SSLProxyProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
```

is all that you need.

If you want to support "later" in a more flexible way, just do:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
```

For Apache 2.4, these are the only protocols supported.